# Restarting an XMLHttpRequest on receiving a 404 response

Tags: javascript, cors

I have the following method that iterates over an array containing objects that have a URL property (floodAreaData[0].polygon) which I fetch over an XMLHttpRequest, the results of which are passed to `loadFloodAreaPolygon` function.

This is working as expected, my issue I've run into is that one of the URLs is returning a 404, and causes the following error to be displayed in the console window:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/floodAreas/051WACDV5B3a/polygon' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I've spent more time than I'd like trying to implement a CORS policy without any luck and increasing frustration.

My question is can I just reset the XMLRequest to continue processing from the next available URL? I tried adding a try catch block but for some reason the message within is not getting printed to the console when I test..

```
function getFloodAreaPolygon() {
  try {
    if (floodAreaData.length > 0) {
      let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      let url = floodAreaData[0].polygon;
      request.open("GET", url, true);
      request.onload = function () {
        let data = JSON.parse(this.response);
        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
          data.features.forEach(geojsonFeature => {
            loadFloodAreaPolygon(floodAreaData[0], geojsonFeature);
            floodAreaData.shift();
            getFloodAreaPolygon();
          });
        } else {
          console.log("error");
        }
      };
      request.send();
    }
  } catch {
    console.log("request error");
  }
}
```

Comment: Just two thoughts: 1) You can't possibly add CORS headers in British government sites unless you're, well, the government 2) try / catch is pretty much useless unless someone throws

Comment: Regarding CORS: if you could simply implement a CORS policy to solve this, why have CORS in the first place? No, that error essentially means that you cannot use that API from the JS client side of your website; it's supposed to be used from the backend (where CORS is a non-issue).

Comment: If the 404 response doesn’t have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header, then browsers block your frontend JavaScript code from accessing any properties of the response — including `.status`. Or to put it in other terms, if a response has no Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header, there’s no way for your frontend JavaScript code to programatically determine whether it was a 404 (or any other response status you might want to check for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The load event only fires if the request is successful. If it isn't, then you get an error event.

If there is a network or CORS error then the status of the XHR object will be `0`. You can't distinguish between types of status 0 error from JS (the developer console will display more information, but your code running on someone else's computer can't).

So write an error handler, test to see if the status is 0, and if it is: Call whatever function will make your code request "the next available URL" (it isn't clear how your code does that in the first place, but I guess it would involve calling `getFloodAreaPolygon` and passing an argument to make it use a different index on the line `let url = floodAreaData[0].polygon;`).

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://example.com/404");
xhr.addEventListener("error", event => {
  console.log({event, xhr});
  if (xhr.status === 0) {
    console.log("Network or CORS error");
    // continue processing from the next available URL
  }
});
xhr.send();
```